# "Reindex" only fills the first two rows with new values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, reindex

I am new to stackoverflow. I hope I can formulate my question clearly.

I am using `reindex` to fill out missing dates in a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.dat', skiprows=1)
print(df)
```

output:

```
               TIME          A             B             C             D
0  2022-04-28 00:02:00       0             2             1             5
1  2022-04-28 00:03:00       0             2             2             5
2  2022-04-28 00:05:00       0             2             3             5
3  2022-04-28 00:06:00       0             2             4             5
4  2022-04-28 00:09:00       0             2             5             5
5  2022-04-28 00:10:00       0             2             6             5
6  2022-04-28 00:12:00       0             2             8             5
7  2022-04-28 00:15:00       0             2            10             5
```

The doing:

```
#Change data type to datetime
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format=date_format)

#define index and round it (The math. floor() method rounds a number DOWN to the nearest integer)
idx = pd.date_range(start='2022-04-28 00:00:00', end='2022-04-28 00:15:00', freq='60S').floor('60S')

#Set index on 'TIME' from 'df'
df = df.set_index('TIME')

#Use 'resample()' as a convenience method for frequency conversion and resampling of time series
df = df.resample('60S').sum()

#Reindex and setting new values to 0
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=1000)
print(df)
```

Where the ouput is:

```
                         A              B              C            D
2022-04-28 00:00:00    1000          1000          1000          1000
2022-04-28 00:01:00    1000          1000          1000          1000
2022-04-28 00:02:00       0             2             1             5
2022-04-28 00:03:00       0             2             2             5
2022-04-28 00:04:00       0             0             0             0
2022-04-28 00:05:00       0             2             3             5
2022-04-28 00:06:00       0             2             4             5
2022-04-28 00:07:00       0             0             0             0
2022-04-28 00:08:00       0             0             0             0
2022-04-28 00:09:00       0             2             5             5
2022-04-28 00:10:00       0             2             6             5
2022-04-28 00:11:00       0             0             0             0
2022-04-28 00:12:00       0             2             8             5
2022-04-28 00:13:00       0             0             0             0
2022-04-28 00:14:00       0             0             0             0
2022-04-28 00:15:00       0             2            10             5
```

My question is: Why does `reindex` creates new dates (as it should) but only sets the value of the first two rows to 1000 instead of all new rows?

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0):

> Why does reindex creates new dates (as it should) but only sets the
> value of the first two rows to 1000 instead of all new rows?

Because fill_value parameter of the [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) is the value to use for missing values. Defaults to NaN, but can be any “compatible” value.

I suggest that you just remove the fill_value=1000 and simply assign 1000 to all columns after reindexing.

Comment: Your welcome. There are many ways to assign 1000 value in all your columns. I don't want to spoil you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a closer look, you will see, after resampling your `df` the index range is from `02:00` to `15:00` but your created `idx` has a range from `0:00` to `15:00`. The only missing values when reindexing are the first two rows, that's why only these two rows get filled with your defined `fill_value`